# Add View as first child

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I am developing an app with a ScrollView were most of the Views in it is added to a RelativeLayout at onCreate. Like this:
[image]

I also want to add Views during runtime. These are added to the current position at the image above. What I want to do is add Views in the wanted position during runtime.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the layout inside the `ScrollView` to a `LinearLayout` as was suggested and than use the:

[`addView(child, index, layoutParams)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)

on your `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer contains in the last line (parent.addView(brick, **0**);), but for exclude misunderstandings i've posted all code.
Right now i'm doing the same

**xml**
`activity_view.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`tpl_yellow_brick.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_width="42p"
>
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm square yellow brick"            
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**java**

```
View brick = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tpl_yellow_brick, null);
ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
parent.addView(brick, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

set this for scroll view 
  `android:orientation="vertical"` and `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: The screen is actually at landscapemode with the scrollview going from the top to the bottom of the screen. And the scroll and realtive layout defined in java. Do you know how to solve this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout and set `android:orientation="vertical"`.

Within this LinearLayout, you can nest another LinearLayout for your horizontal views with `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

In this way, For each horizontal view section, you can add a child LinearLayout to your parent Linearlayout and each of these children will be arranged vertically one below the other as you require.